# Pointer to a const structure, can members still be modified?

Tags: c

I have a structure which I want to pass to some external c code via some callback function that they register with my program. However, I want to pass that structure as *read-only*. My concern is that they can still modify the structures which I have pointer to inside the original structure that I pass. Explained with small example below:

```
struct s1 {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct s2 {
    int x;
    struct s1 *y;
};

void f(const struct s2 *o)
{
    //o->x=10; //error
    o->y->a=20; //no error
    o->y->b=30; //no error
}

int main()
{
    struct s1 o1 = {10, 20};
    struct s2 o2 = {30, &o1};
    f(&o2);
}
```

So, How do I improve my code design so that they cannot modify anything w.r.t the structure I pass?

Comment: Do you want to allow them to read some parameters? If not, you may use *forward declaration* approach to hide some members from public code, make it visible only in private section of your library. Based on your answer I will give you official answer.

Comment: What you can do is define the struct in a .c file. From all header function you typedef a void* for your type and other functions that belong to a public api of you type. Then from the callback you cannot see the members and only use the public functions of the type.

Comment: @tilz0R Yes, they should be able to read all the members. They'll take different actions depending on what the value of that member is.

Comment: To fully hide, you will have to create getter functions in your library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To properly handle this situation, you can only use forward declaration to hide members together with getter and setter functions.

Focus on code below and check:

- `struct s1` only has *forward declaration* so you can make a pointer to it in `struct s2`.
- Actual implementation of `struct s1` is in `mylib.c` thus all members are only visible to your library and not to user.
- Getters and setters are implemented to set/read the value to these hidden members as only your library has access to members, making it completely hidden from user.
- This forces him to use your functions.

mylib.h:

```
#ifndef __MYLIB_H
#define __MYLIB_H

//Create forward declaration only
//Implementation is in .c file
struct s1;

//Create user structure
struct s2 {
  int x;
  struct s1* y;
};

int get_a_from_s1(struct s2* s);
void set_a_to_s1(struct s2* s, int a);

#endif /* __MYLIB_H */
```

mylib.c:

```
#include "mylib.h"

//Now implement structure
struct s1 {
  int a, b;
};

//Make getter
int
get_a_from_s1(struct s2* s) {
  return s->y->a;
}

//Make setter
void
set_a_to_s1(struct s2* s, int a) {
  s->y->a = a;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main(void) {
  struct s2 s;
  int a;

  ....

  s.y->a = 5; //error

  //Set s1.a value from s2 structure
  set_a_to_s1(&s, 10); //OK

  //To view members of s1 inside s2, create member functions
  a = get_a_from_s1(&s); //OK

  printf("a: %d\r\n", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, please make sure that `->y` is not `NULL` or you have undefined behavior.

Comment: For the record, this kind of design pattern with incomplete type of `struct s1` in the header is called _opaque type_ or _opaque pointers_.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. Even if you pass the `struct s2` by value, you will get in the function a pointer to a non const `struct s1`, simply because it is what `s2` contains *per its definition*.

And once you have a pointer to a non const object you can change that object. What I mean here and what other answers mean, is that it is not a language problem - more exactly the language can nothing for you here - but a design problem. If for any reason it is not acceptable that the `struct s1` can be changed from `f` then you have to find a different design where you do not pass a non const pointer to it, be it member of a const struct or not. Here a simple way would be to pass the individual members:

```
void f(int x, const struct s1 *y) {
    y->a = 20;  // error
}
```

It may not be what you expect, but it is the best I can say for C language.

Comment: Yes, I also think that passing all members one by one is the only way.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the second struct declaration like so:

```
struct s2 {
    int x;
    struct s1 const *y;
};
```

The added `const` ensures that y is read-only.

Comment: Yes, But that way I myself can't modify y.

Comment: Yes, you can if you cast it back!           ((struct s1 *) (o->y))->b=30;

Comment: @It'scominghome One scenario would be if you want to publish it as part of an API or library and make sure that users of it don't change it accidentally.

Comment: @memo very ugly and may introduce undefined behavior.

Comment: @tilz0R I just answered the question, not that I would recommend it

Comment: @Raman Where are you trying to modify value of `y`? If it's in the same scope as it's declared, you could do `var.y=&var2` where `var` is a `struct s2`.

Comment: Casting back certainly works, but I would stress the fact that the variable assigned to `y` must not be declared with const.

Answer (score 2):

In `f()`, `const struct s2 *o` means in the `struct s2` being pointed to by `o`, the values of its members ie, `x` and `y` cannot be changed.

With `o->y->a=20`, you are not modifying the value of `y`. You are just using that address to modify a member of the structure being pointed to by `y` and `y`'s value, which is an address, remains the same.

So those 2 lines will give no error.

I could see no way to avoid this unless you could make the `struct s2` definition to

```
struct s2 {
    int x;
    const struct s1 *y;
};
```

in which case `y` is a pointer to a constant `struct s1`.

See the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and visit the [cdecl](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) website.

Answer (score 0):

I would write another function that takes in a const struct s1 * to modify the values of s1.